# Fresh install ubuntu 14.04 not detecting wifi

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron 14. It does not list any WiFi network, Ethernet works fine though.

`lspci` command gives the following output.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

How to get the wifi working?

Comment: Don't install a 4 year old distribution, find something more up2date.

Comment: Do you know what your model number actually is from atheros? You may have to pop it open and look. Update your question when you find it.